# Django:Run pylint on all the apps in one go

Tags: django, pylint

I want to run pylint recursively on all my project apps from the root of the app. If i use : `pylint .` on the root of the project base, it gives me the error that there is no **init**.

How can I run the pylint from my project root without having to specify all the apps one by one.

**EDIT**
Thank you heartily for the downvotes. But since I am a novice at that and still couldnt find a solution to my issue, can the downvoters please explain or the give the oh-so-obvious solution?  If this is how pylint is designed to be called recursively on each app, then can you point me to the documentation?

Comment: Thank you heartily for the downvotes. But since I am a novice at that and still couldnt find a solution to my issue, can the downvoters please explain or the give the oh-so-obvious solution?  If this is how pylint is designed to be called recursively on each app, then can you point me to the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by default the pylint is requires the module name or the file name to be linted to be provided to it as args and it does not automatically recursively search from the pwd. It would however lint every python file in a module if a module name is provided.

In order to run the pylint without the hassle of having to maintain the apps, I am using :

```
PyCQA/prospector
```